# Possible end users of virtualization platforms

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machine

I am looking out for possible end users of virtualization tools like VM Ware or Hyper V etc.
Couple of groups I could think of are Developers, Corporate customers. I could not think of more because I have very very limited knowledge in virtualization.

Does virtualization need any OS support? Say I have to use a virtualization tool like VM Ware on Ubuntu does Ubuntu have to tweak its code to make VM Ware run on its releases or something. Please clarify.

Thanks a bunch for your time.

Regards,
J

Answer (score 0):

### Legacy support

Think about

> I have this piece of software that runs on FooOS for Workgroups 3.1 and nothing newer which supports downloads from my personal FrobnicationMeterizer. Do I *really* have to keep a antique box in the corner of my office just to run it?!?

// in my case FooOS for Workgroups 3.1 is actually Windows XP, and the FrobnicationMeterizer is actually the better half's insulin pump.

Answer (score 0):

> Does virtualization need any OS
>   support? Say I have to use a
>   virtualization tool like VM Ware on
>   Ubuntu does Ubuntu have to tweak its
>   code to make VM Ware run on its
>   releases or something?

Ubuntu nor Windows will tweak their code to run any virtualization tool on it, the tools are the ones to tweak their code to support new releases.